# How do I track site loading and tag latency over time using chrome on the server?

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, phantomjs, google-chrome-devtools, selenium-chromedriver

With an increasing mobile user base I would like to be able to gauge a baseline for site performance. Typically I can do this using chrome dev tools, checking when DOMContentLoaded finishes, and checking all my javascript tags to make sure they're in acceptable threshholds. How would I go about automating this so I can create performance dashboards?

Maybe phantomjs, selenium can do this? What headless chrome implementation could I use to achieve this.

Comment: phantomjs has hooks for before an asset is requested and after it's received so maybe you can use that to time them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Lighthouse](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/lighthouse/) to capture a variety of performance metrics.

For [real user metrics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_user_monitoring), you can instrument your app however you see fit with the [User Timing API](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webperformance/usertiming/).